# Op amp problem - unexpected simulation results

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I am referring to the accepted answer in this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57824/how-do-i-get-5v-for-loud-noise-0v-for-silence-from-electret-microphone-or-oth)

The answer has 25 votes, and is picked as the best answer but after carefully reviewing it, I could only come to a conclusion that it is not accurate or that I am missing something.

Here is the original Circuit:
[image]

**A**, What is the point of this so-called super-diode, where the last stage has already been off-set to vcc/2? (meaning the signal from last stage are all positive)

Here is my simulation. Clearly it's different than the simulation from the original answer.
[image]

**B**, That is a just differential amplifier however, it seems to be stretching the signal. It seems to me that in first stage, he adds (off-set) vcc/2 to the signal, and the last stage, he subtracts vcc/2 from the signal.

I am wondering whether I am missing something. Otherwise, I am wondering what the correct answer to the original question is.

**Update: Here is a complete simulation.**
[image]

[image]

**Update 2:**
I think I got it now. The circuit requires a real sound wave as input.
[image]

Comment: The linked answer looks good to me. I'm not sure what you don't understand about it. For the precision rectifier ("super-diode"), do you understand why we want an envelope follower? For the differential amplifier, of course it amplifies ("stretches") the signal, that's literally its name.

Comment: Your circuit is NOT the same as the original.  Duplicate the original, then see if it works as it should.

Comment: A diode lets current pass if the voltage is higher from anode to cathode.  It doesn't matter if the voltage at both ends is positive - there just has to be a difference.

Comment: Also, if you can't trust a given answer, how could you trust that a new answer is trustworthy?

Comment: ::Boggle:: The output isn't supposed to look like the input.  It is supposed to represent the peak voltage of the input. So, an (approximately) DC voltage proportional to the 0.05 V of the signal generator.  Which is what the red trace shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A**: The linked article explains that the op-amp / diode combination eliminates the normal voltage drop associated with rectification. For a small signal a regular diode's \$ V_f \$ is too high and would either distort or block the signal. Putting it into an amplifier with feedback eliminates the effect of diode voltage drop.

> What is the point of this so-called super-diode, where the last stage has already been off-set to vcc/2? (meaning the signal from last stage are all positive).

The purpose of section A is not signal rectification but rather peak envelope detection in conjunction with C3. The signal is at positive voltage all the way through. The peak detector will be biased above \$ V_{cc}/2 \$.

**B**: This is a standard non-inverting amplifier operating around \$ V_{cc}/2 \$. This is standard practice in audio circuits powered from a single-ended supply.

Comment: You are, of course, correct.  But, I think part of the problem is an understanding of how a diode works.  Atmega328 seems to believe that a diode only lets current flow if one side had a positive voltage and the other a negative voltage.  The bit with eliminating the forward voltage seems to have gotten through.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell what exactly the problem is other than attitude. (See question revision history.)

Comment: Yeah, I saw it "real time."

Answer (score 1):

The original circuit is a peak detector (aka envelope detector) with a hold capacitor of 10 uF and a discharge resistor of 26.7 kohm (\$\tau\$ of 267 ms).

Your circuit's hold capacitor in 10 nF and of course it won't perform correctly with your input stimulus of 1 kHz because 10 nF || 22 kohm has a \$\tau\$ of 0.22 ms whereas the original has a \$\tau\$ of 267 ms.

Comment: I know it's a 10uf, but I didn't get the expected result, so I changed it to 10nf. Here I updated a complete and "correct" simulation, and the result is more than disappointing, or what should I say, expected?

Comment: @Atmega328 It looks like your new simulation hits the spot precisely. The envelope detector appears to function rather well. Maybe you were expecting something else to happen?

Comment: the result (out) doesn't seem right to me. The input is a sin-wave, but the output is NOT.

Comment: The circuit is designed to capture the peak of the sinewave i.e. it is an envelope (or peak) amplitude measurement circuit. For a sine wave of peak value 1 in you get 1 volt (possibly scaled) out. I think you think the circuit is intended to perform some other function yes?

Comment: I got it now, although the responsive result from my simulation is not ideal.